# The opinion that microwaves don't need to be kashered

Tags: sources-mekorot, kashrut-kosher, cooking-bishul, appliances, acharonim

So I remember hearing this opinion that followed like this: "Microwaves do not need to be kashered because the means of cooking in a microwave are different than those spoken about in the Gemara."

Which opinion is this? I remember hearing a stipulation about making sure that the surface you heat the food on is kosher (no treif plates) because the plate may heat up and cook the underside of the food, but this opinion generally allowed a Jew to use any microwave. Is this a paraphrase of Rabbi Shlomo Auerbach or who else?

Comment: The star-K [says](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-cooking-microwave.htm) it. Perhaps ask them for who their source is (although if they say it, I would assume R. Heinemann agrees).

Comment: it is r heinenmans own opinion.

Comment: @Nafkamina You should make that into an answer then.

Comment: Rabbi Berger from Ner Israel agrees with the Star-K ruling.